# Filtrar matriz de strings em C e contar quantas se repetem

Tags: c, array, c++, string, matriz

O programa faz locações de carro, é preciso de placa e o tipo do carro, ambos armazenados em duas matrizes diferentes, como faço para pegar apenas as placas dos carros do tipo luxo.
Código q fiz até agora

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char luxo[100]="luxo";

char type[100][100];
char typeCar[100][100];

char board[100][100];
char boardOpc[100][100];
char aux[100];

int quantity = 0, i = 0, j = 0, count = 0; //quantidade de locaçoes

int compar = 0, comparType = 0;

int client[100];

int payment[100];

int countA = 0, countB = 0, countC = 0, sair = 1;

while(sair==1){
    printf("Digite o tipo do veículo preferencialmente sem acento e letra minúscula: ");
    scanf("%s", type[countA]);
    printf("Digite a placa do veículo: ");
    scanf("%s", board[countA]);
    printf("Para continuar cadastrando mais uma locação digite 1, para ver as outras opções digite 0\n");
    scanf("%d", &sair);
    countA++;
}

sair = 1;
for(i;i<countA;i++) {
                for(j=i+1;j<countA;j++) {
                    if(compar=strcmp(board[i], board[j]) > 0) {
                        strcpy(aux,board[i]);
                        strcpy(board[i],board[j]);
                        strcpy(board[j],aux);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            count = 1;
            for(i=0;i<countA;i++){
                if(compar=strcmp(board[i],board[i+1]) == 0){
                    if(compar=strcmp(type[i], luxo)==0) {
                        printf("AQ");
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    
                    for(i=0;i<countA;i++) {
                        for(j=i+1;j<countA; j++) {
                            if(compar = strcmp(board[i], board[j])>0) {
                                strcpy(aux,board[i]);
                                strcpy(board[i],board[j]);
                                strcpy(board[j],aux);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    for(i=0; i<countA; i++){
                        /*if(compar = strcmp(board[i], board[i+1])==0) {
                            if(comparType=strcmp(type[i], "luxo")==0) {
                                count++;
                            }
                        } else*/ if(compar = strcmp(type[i], luxo)==0) {
                            printf("Entrou AW");
                            printf("A placa %s aparece %d vezes\n", board[i], count);
                            
                            count=1;
                        }
                    }
                    if(compar=strcmp(type[i], luxo)==0){
                        printf("Entrou AQUI");
                        printf("A placa %s aparece %d vezes\n", board[i], count);
                    }
                }
            }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Todos os seus dados estão soltos, isto é, um vetor não tem relação com o outro e isso deixa o programa difícil de ler e alterar. Uma alternativa é usar structs para relacionar os dados entre si. Exemplo:

```
struct tipo_carro
{
    char tipo[100];
    char placa[100];
};
typedef struct tipo_carro Carro;
```

Agora o tipo do carro está totalmente relacionado a sua placa e isso facilita identificar um tipo apenas usando a placa e vice e versa.

```
Carro carro[100];
```

Acima eu criei um vetor do tipo carro onde posso ter 100 carros diferentes, cada um deles com um tipo e uma placa. Para verificar todas as placas do tipo luxo basta fazer isso:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(carro[i].tipo, luxo) == 0)
    {
        // Aqui será ativado quando encontrar um carro de luxo
        // Então basta fazer `carro[i].placa` para acessar a placa
    }
}
```

Veja esses links sobre structs caso você não conheça esse tipo de dado:
[Structs - 1](https://www.inf.pucrs.br/%7Epinho/LaproI/Structs/Structs.htm)
[Structs - 2](http://linguagemc.com.br/struct-em-c/)

Comment: Blz obrigado vou dar uma olhada